# Designing Large banners in illustrator cs4

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am designibg a banner 6' by 4' at what resolution should an image 2' by 3.5' I would like to use be?

Comment: It seems like your question could be improved. At which resolution are you printing or at what viewing distance will the banner be? Also, is your image in Illustrator like the tag might imply?

Comment: Is this going to be a printed banner or an on screen banner e.g. a website banner?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how your banner is going to be printed. The usual approach is to assume that the banner will be printed at 72 pixels per inch - which sounds very coarse, but remember it will be seen from a distance.

So size your image in Photoshop by making a new document 24 x 42 inches at 72ppi, which will result in a file of 1728 x 3024 pixels.